# jquery mobile hashing problem with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am using jquery mobile. It comes with a hashing functionality to hash navigated pages to improve speed.
For example:
page a-> page b.

Page b will be hashed and you will see #blabla in your url when you go to page b.

However, the problem I has is:

I have some javascript needs to run on page b immediately after page is ready, so I included it in page b. The first access went well, but the second one will screw up. Does anybody have ways to solve this.

Thanks

OK here is the sample code

page a:

```
<div>
<a href="page b"> page b </a>
</div>
```

page b:

```
<div>
<h3> I am page b </h3>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.alert("running")
</script>
</div>
```

Jquery mobile framework will hash page b. So when you click the anchor to navigate to page b,  the url will be like xxxx\a#\a\b.

However, the javascript fire only at the first time you land on page b. I want to have it fired every time.

Comment: How did you include it in page b?

Comment: Fix the problem. Without code or examples, that's the best advice you'll get.

Comment: I personally think Jquery mobile is really bad, give it up, whatever you're doing it's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

The script only runs once when the page is loaded, but jqm is caching your page, so it only runs the first time the page is retrieved - you need to bind to the "pageshow" event to run code every time the page is shown.